# Getting a chrome.storage value from a string variable?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, storage

I have a variable url that is set as my `chrome.storage.set` `key` but for some reason anything I try will not bring up the value of the key?

```
var url = window.location.href;`
var orderTotal = 44;

 chrome.storage.sync.set({url: orderTotal }, function () {
    alert('Data saved');
  });


  let usrDta = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    chrome.storage.sync.get(url, function (result) {
      resolve(result);
    });
  });
```

tried many different ways but anything with a return just comes up as `{https://www.urlString....com: 44}` im just trying to get the value of `44`

```
  usrDta.then(function (usrDta) {

    console.log(usrDta);
    console.log(usrDta.url);
    console.log(url.usrDta);
    console.log(usrDta, url);
    console.log(url, usrDta);
    console.log(usrDta.usrDta);

  })

.catch(function (reason) {
        console.log("Handle rejected promise (" + reason + ") here.");
      });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access a property with variable key, use `[]`, like `usrDta[url]`.